# Take Sum of time difference and Last value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table in which we store the `StartTime` and `StopTime` for a task. One task can be assigned to multiple technicians. One task can have multiple start times, stop times (so multiple rows, here Doc Num is primary ID).

> I want to calculate Sum of difference between Start time and Stop time based on Task ID and Technician ID.

Also I need to take the status of last row to determine the Current Status of the Task for each Technician. I tried following query. But it didn't work.

```
SELECT T1.TaskId, SUM(DATEDIFF(second, T1.StartTime,T1.StopTime)) as TaskDuration
    , T3.TechnicianId, T3.FinalStatus 
FROM Tbl_TaskTracking T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT T2.TaskId, T2.technicianId
        , first_Value(T2.Status) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.TASKID, T2.technicianId ORDER BY T2.TASKID, T2.technicianId, T2.docnum desc) AS FinalStatus
    FROM Tbl_TaskTracking T2
) AS T3 ON T1.TaskId = T3.TaskId
WHERE T1.TaskId = '2001628'
GROUP BY T1.TaskId, T3.TechnicianId, T3.FinalStatus
```

My table data look like this. This rows showing data for a particular Task ID.

[image: SQL Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the following in your join `on` clause:

```
AND T1.TechnicianId = T3.TechnicianId
```

It's like this:

```
SELECT T1.TaskId
      ,SUM(DATEDIFF(second, T1.StartTime,T1.StopTime)) as TaskDuration
      ,T3.TechnicianId
      ,T3.FinalStatus 
FROM Tbl_TaskTracking T1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT  T2.TaskId
                    ,T2.technicianId
                    ,first_Value(T2.Status) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.TASKID,T2.technicianId ORDER BY T2.TASKID,T2.technicianId,T2.docnum desc) AS FinalStatus
    FROM Tbl_TaskTracking T2
) AS T3 
    ON T1.TaskId = T3.TaskId
    AND T1.TechnicianId = T3.TechnicianId
WHERE T1.TaskId = '2001628'
GROUP BY T1.TaskId
        ,T3.TechnicianId
        ,T3.FinalStatus
```